# Why does rails ignore .bundle by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Isn't the point of the project .bundle/config to specify config that is relevant to the project?

Comment: Can you provide more information? What is the contents of this file and what version of bundle and rails are you using?

Comment: rails 3, newest bundler, contents isn't anything, but contents of .gitignore generated by `rails new foo` ignores .bundle

Comment: Updated my answer take a look.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the `bundle-config` [manpage](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html) is says:

> This command allows you to interact with bundler's configuration
>   system. Bundler retrieves its configuration from the local application
>   (app/.bundle/config), environment variables, and the user's home
>   directory (~/.bundle/config), in that order of priority.
>   So ensure that you don't have any configuration files that are taking priority over the one you want to use.

You can configure this file yourself or set options using `bundle config (option)`, running `bundle config` without any options prints the current configuration.
For example you can set compile time options for they mysql gem like so:

```
bundle config build.mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

So yes, `app/.bundle/config` is used to set bundle options for the current project.

**Edit:**
This change was added in commit efa85055 to the Rails github repo. You can view that version of the [file here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blame/ae4cb0641ed5505c99f3ba6eef35a83c263bfe98/.gitignore) and the [commit here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/efa850558facf2fbaaf226f1444802da83924b82).

The commit message is from [José Valim](https://github.com/josevalim) and mentions the line you have a question about:

> Make bin/rails call rails/commands/application, fix generators usage
>   and update .gitignores.

**Edit Again:**
This is a [quote from bundler](https://bundler.io/rationale.html) on why you should not check the .bundle directory into any VCS.

> Do not check in the .bundle directory, or any of the files inside it.
>   Those files are specific to each particular machine, and are used to
>   persist installation options between runs of the bundle install
>   command.

Comment: That's an informative overview, but you didn't answer the question about why the config is ignored by default. :) I guess the obvious ansewr is that the point is to give individual users control of bundler's behavior per-project -- but it's too bad that things can't be better, with bundler and rvm being more simple and consistent on all systems...

Comment: What do you mean by ignored? There is no mention of this in the documentation and I dont think thats the expected behavour. If you have options set in `app/.bundle/config` they should be used.

Comment: Ah you mean ignored by git. Well its most likely a security concern and not something that a developer would normally distribute with a source package or VCS.

Comment: No I mean, by default **rails** tells **git** to ignore **.bundle/***

Comment: Yes so in other words git ignores .bundle like I said. The default ignore file for git generated by rails has this set up, If you look at my post you can see when this was added and the commit message.

Comment: Just found the reasoning behind the choice. `.bundle` is not a per app configuration it is used to persist installation options and the files are specific per machine.

Comment: It is per machine, but also per project. That is, you can have a global ~/.bundle/config that ensures certain gems always use a particular option, but you can override those at the app/.bundle/config level, in case you are building gems a particular way for the project.

Comment: @xentek The file in the project folder is still machine specific and should not be transferred.